# How do I trim leading zeros from a regular expression capture group?

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression that splits an 18 digit number into 4 capture groups (saved at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3FQhtx/2)).

```
/(\d{5})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{9})/mg
```

Using `000012022000456789` as the test string, my result is:

Group 1: `00001`
Group 2: `20`
Group 3: `22`
Group 4: `000456789`

I also need to trim leading zeros from Group 1, so my **desired** result is:

Group 1: `1`
Group 2: `20`
Group 3: `22`
Group 4: `000456789`

Can this all be done using one regular expression? Note that this is a general regular expression question, not specific to an engine or language.

Comment: Try this: ^0*([1-9])

Comment: Is is guaranteed that the input is always a 18-digit number?

Comment: @blhsing Yes, it is guaranteed the input is always an 18-digit number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a non-capturing group to absorb up to 4 leading zeros, and adjust your first capturing group to match from 1 to 5 digits:

```
(?:0{0,4})(\d{1,5})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{9})
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Gcl1N0/1)

As long as your input is always an 18-digit number, this will work fine. If however the input could be other than 18 digits, this might match something like `01122333333333` or `000001111122333333333`.

You can work around this by adding a lookbehind assertion before the second group that requires it to be preceded by exactly 5 digits and an assertion that the string be terminated by a non-digit:

```
(?:0{0,4})(\d{1,5})(?<=\b\d{5})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{9})(?=\b)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aTchFJ/2)

Comment: Yes, the input is always an 18-digit number. Your first solution works perfectly for various example inputs that I tested it against. The first group should never be all zeros, but if it was then the result is 0 for that group, which is actually the preferred outcome if that would happen. Thanks!

Comment: @DaleM I wasn't sure about the possibility of the number starting with 5 zero's but figured even if it did you would still want something captured in the first group. Anyway, I'm glad I could help.